# How to just get plain text and line breaks using XSL

Tags: xslt

With this input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <data> 
This is a senstence   
this is another sentence

<section>
        <!--comment --><h2>my H2</h2>     <p>some paragraph</p>             <p>another paragraph</p>                 
    </section> </data>
```

I need to apply XSL style sheet to obtain just the plain text, honor the line breaks, and remove preceeding white space. So, after searching online for a few samples, I tried this, but it does not work for me. Sorry, Im not familiar with XSL and thought I'd ask.

Attempted XSL, but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

        <xsl:template match ="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>    
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="h1|h2">
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>  
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output after applying XSL.
As you can see, its all one line, not carriage returns.

```
This is a sentence this is another sentence m H2some paragraphTanother paragraph
```

This is the output I'd like to get. Text within H1|H2|H3 should have a line break before and after.

```
This is a sentence 
this is another sentence 

my H2

some paragraph
another paragraph
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean ? Does it show an error message ? Does it do something you do not want it to do ? Does it spew out a midget ?

Comment: Consider to post the plain text output you want for the XML input sample you posted.

Comment: Thanks! I meant to include those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to maintain the carriage return within `xml:text`, and you need a carriage return before and after the content of `h1` and `h2` tags:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match ="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h1|h2">
    <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The initial text (`This is a senstence`, `this is another sentence`) is output correctly on separate lines in my case (using Visual Studio 2012 to execute the XSLT).

You write that only `h` tags should have the carriage return added - in your sample `some paragraph` and `another paragraph` are in `p` tags, so no carriage returns are added and they are output on the same line.

Comment: `<xsl:text>` automatically preserves spaces, you don't need the `xml:space` on there.  But generally I prefer to use `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` to insert a newline, as that means I can safely re-indent the XSLT file without changing the semantics.

Comment: @IanRoberts: depends on how you load/execute the XSLT - it is non-significant white space and so it (can) get stripped if `xml:space="preserve"` is not there

Comment: [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) says that `<xsl:text>` should always preserve space.  If it doesn't then that's a bug in the processor.  You have a point though, that there could be issues if the processor isn't in control of the XSLT parsing process (e.g. if another component parses the .xsl file into a DOM tree with space stripped, then hands that DOM to the XSLT processor).

Comment: @Mimo I've tried to verify that this works using XML Notepad and an online XSL tool by W3school, but neither tool shows line breaks when that XSL is applied. Not sure if its the tool or something else that I'm missing. :(

Comment: @Mimo I've confirmed this works using Visual Studio 2010. Odd the others tools don't show it working. Thanks though!